# Valor por default a un input en HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un formulario que va a registrar nombre,apellidos, etc. y tengo un campo que pide un número, ya registro bien, ahora quisiera que si el campo número va vacío que inserte algo por default, ejemplo : 0.

En el formulario obtengo el valor del input así:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Número</label>
    <input type="number"  name="no"  class="form-control" placeholder="23" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['no'])) echo $_POST['no'];  else echo "0" ?>" />
</div>
```

PHP:

```
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
    $db_handle = new DBController();




if(!empty($_POST['no'])){
     $username = $_POST['no'];
}

if(empty($_POST['userName'])){
     $username = '8787';
}

$query = "INSERT INTO tabla (.....,no_interior,...) VALUES
    (...,'" . $username . "',,...)";
```

Pero no me registra nada en la bd.

Gracias.

Comment: Podrias intentar un if dentro de tu archivo php donde si es nulo registre los mismos campos pero para ese en especifico envias 0, por cierto ya verificaste que la conexión a tu base de datos funcione ?

Comment: Sí, en la pregunta dije que si registra bien. Pero si va vacío algo no registra.

Comment: El colocar un valor por default en caso de que no se ingrese nada debería ser tarea del backend, como comenta Max Sandoval podrías poner un if donde el valor es nulo, pero si deseas mas orientación por favor coloca también la función de php donde estas recuperando los valores e insertándolos en la DB

Comment: @HoracioSanchez Ya coloqué la query, si me podrías explicar un poco, no es proyecto real, solo practico, gracias.

Comment: Al momento que dices no me registra nada en la bd, ¿te refieres a que no se ejecuta el query, o que te guarda datos en blanco?

Comment: No me registra nada, por lo tanto no se ejecuta la query

Comment: Revisa los logs de apache para ver que error te genera, para saber de forma especifica el error que no deja que se ejecute el query.

Comment: Comparte la consulta completa y el código donde recuperas los valores, además del mensaje que recibes tras ejecutar la query, o va a ser casi imposible saber qué está pasando.

Comment: Aparte de eso, usar SQL dinámicas es mala práctica. Tal y como está el código arriba, puede sufrir ataques de inyección de SQL.

Comment: El código también puede sufrir ataques XSS. Deberías sanear TODAS las entradas del usuario antes de usarlas. Tanto en el back-end como en front-end

Answer (score 1):

La solución más sencilla:

```
if (isset($_POST['no'])) {
    $username = $_POST['no'];
}
else {
    $username = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo te sugiero que revises la variable, puede que no se mande vacia.

Prueba con `IS_NULL` o con `""` en tu `if` para que primero identifiques que estas recibiendo cuando el campo va "vacio"

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas Mysql puedes configurar la tabla de manera que inserte valores por defecto si no se le asigna ningún valor con la Query.

[image: Valor por defecto PhpmMyAdmin]